# how to push multiple userid in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array with yes or no values. I want to add the user which has no value. This I want use on bar chart to show the output.

```
foreach ($ansarry as $queno => $value) {
    if ($value == 'yes') {
        $count++;
    } else {
        $user_array[] = $fetchrat->user_id;
        $uu = array_unique($user_array);
        $uimpl = implode(",", $uu);

        $noques[] = $queno;

        $participant[$sectionno][$queno] = $uimpl;
        $countno++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Post some errors.

Comment: its not throw any error its not working correctly i want to add the participant which has given 'no' answer 

$participant[$sectionno][$queno]=$uimpl;

Comment: What does the multidimensional array look like? what are some default values? Add these to the question.

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => yes
            [2] => no
            [3] => yes
            [4] => yes
            [5] => yes
            [6] => yes
            [7] => yes
            [8] => yes
            [9] => yes
            [10] => yes
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => no
            [2] => no
            [3] => no
            [4] => no
            [5] => no
            [6] => no
            [7] => no
            [8] => no
            [9] => no
            [10] => no
        )
upto 12

Comment: ex : in above the user id 658 has these output and same the user 567 that if the user 658 and the user 567 has no answer of 1 section of 2 question means the output something like $participant[1][2]=658,567

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question and add some (formatted!) details:

- What's the expected result array?
- What's the (unexpected) result you're getting?
- Use more descriptive variable names (or translate them or explain what they're supposed to do), because we can't know what these are supposed to be: `$ansarry`, `$queno`, ...

Don't forget to use the code formatting, especially for code and variable dumps.

Once you've added details, I'll edit this answer with a complete reply. (I'm at 49 rep so I can't add this as comment below 50.)